# Convert array of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have the following array for example -

```
[
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "5"
  },
]
```

Now, I want to reduce this array into a single object by grouping `value` with the same `name` together into an array. Something like this -

```
{
  abc: [1, 3, 4],
  xyz: [2, 5]
}
```

How do I do this using `reduce` in JavaScript?

I'm not sure if this the right approach but I have tried something like this and it doesn't give me the desired output.

```
const data = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [item.name]: [item.value, acc[item.value]]
  };
});
```

Comment: please may you share a [mcve] of what you have already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with your answer, but you need to check if `acc` already has a key of `item.name`:

```js
const data = [{
    name: "abc",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "5"
  },
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [name] : [...(acc[name] || []), value]
}), {})

console.log(result)
```

Note you can use object destructuring to simplify the accumulation code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data=[
  {
name: "abc",
value: "1"
  },
  {
name: "xyz",
value: "2"
  },
  {
name: "abc",
value: "3"
  },
  {
name: "abc",
value: "4"
  },
  {
name: "xyz",
value: "5"
  },
];

const res=data.reduce((a,c)=>{
 (a[c.name]??=[]).push(c.value);
 return a;
},{});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Or with implicit return: `data.reduce((a,c)=>((a[c.name]??=[]).push(c.value), a),{});`

Comment: I know this is a "code only" answer. But its actions are so simple they speak for themselves.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan with destructuring, `console.log(data.reduce((a, {name, value}) => ((a[name]??=[]).push(value), a), {}));`

Comment: In the end it boils down to a question of style: Do I strive for least repetition, shortest code or best readability?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
    name: "abc",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "5"
  },
];

let finalObject = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
   if (!finalObject.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) {
      finalObject[item.name] = [item.value];
   } else {
      finalObject[item.name].push(item.value);
   }
});
console.log(finalObject);
```

Just parse values if you need in string to number and it will give you answer

```
{
  abc: [1, 3, 4],
  xyz: [2, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the array using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const 
  data = [
    { name: "abc", value: "1" },
    { name: "xyz", value: "2" },
    { name: "abc", value: "3" },
    { name: "abc", value: "4" },
    { name: "xyz", value: "5" },
  ],
  result = data.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.name] ??= []).push(o.value), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

`reduce` takes some time to getting used to, but it's fairly simple once it clicks. You can also group the array using a simple `for...of` loop.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "abc", value: "1" },
  { name: "xyz", value: "2" },
  { name: "abc", value: "3" },
  { name: "abc", value: "4" },
  { name: "xyz", value: "5" },
];

const result = {};
for (let d of data) {
  (result[d.name] ??= []).push(d.value);
}

console.log(result);
```

**Other relevant documentations:**

- [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Nullish Coalescing Operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Comma Operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce()`:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    name: "xyz",
    value: "5"
  },
]

const data = arr.reduce((a,c) => ({...a, [c.name]: a[c.name] ? [...a[c.name], c.value] : [c.value]}),{})
console.log(data)
```