# How to output key and value to create a new object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array and I want to create new object with the keys and values.

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'ab',
    key: '584577',
  },
  {
    name: 'cd',
    key: '344926',
  },
  {
    name: 'ef',
    key: '804816',
  },
];


for(const item of arr) {
  setNewObject({...newObject, [item.name]: item.key})
}
```

But results prints nothing. This is my expected result:

```
   {
      ab: 584577,
      cd: 344926,
      ef: 804816
    }
```

Here's a [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8de3ud?file=src%2FApp.js)
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: set state is asynchronous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Comment: @cmgchess my main issue is that I believe I'm not doing setNewObject({...newObject, [item.name]: item.key}) correctly

Comment: `setNewObject(prev => ({...prev, [item.name]: item.key}))`

Comment: `console.log(newObject)` won't show the changes - newObject will only be updated when you re-render, and your useEffect does not trigger on re-render.  If you put the output of newObject into your html output you would see the properties once it re-renders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874555/how-do-i-convert-array-of-objects-into-one-object-in-javascript)

Comment: or [Convert array of objects into a single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388019/convert-array-of-objects-into-a-single-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: so that it works with for loop as requested

Create a new object and then inside your loop, you assign a new key with its value like this `newObj[item.name] = item.key`

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'ab',
    key: '584577',
  },
  {
    name: 'cd',
    key: '344926',
  },
  {
    name: 'ef',
    key: '804816',
  },
];

let newObj = {}
for(const item of arr) {
    newObj[item.name] = item.key
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I need to stick with "for of"loop as there are more logic inside of it

Comment: let me edit my answer

Comment: what will be the solution using my setter "setNewObject" can you provide a live demo please? I need to store this new object in the state. Thanks

Comment: just after the for loop, do `setNewObject(newObj)`